# Company name in the iOS Individual Developer Plan?

Tags: ios, account

Should I use my real company name in the iOS Individual Developer Plan?

Edit:
I plan on enrolling in the iPhone Developer Program as an individual. While adding my first application on iTunes Connect, does it prompt me to enter a company name? Can I use any fictitious name? Does it have to be a legal entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your own name (I do).  Don't use false information if you're planning on selling apps (as opposed to providing free apps) as Apple will verify the information in the 'Contracts, Tax, and Banking' phase of the application.

Visit iTunes Connect (itunesconnect.apple.com) for more information.

Comment: I totally agree with that and I want to use my name, the primary reason why I don't want to enroll as a company. But I do have a name, Emerys (http://emerys.co) to be the name it's under. I don't know if its still this way, but the seller name was your name and you were able to create like a studio name to put you apps under. You can see what I mean with the author of ClouDrop. I just talked to him and he said he signed up as an individual, but let him enter a studio/company name. I'm trying to figure out if that option is still available.